# DB Error: unknown error when sending CiviMail

Tags: wordpress, civimail, mysql

I recently upgraded my WordPress CiviCRM from 5.25 to 5.28 and in doing so needed to migrate the SQL old 5.5 database to 5.7.  The upgrades went fine, but I now have an error when trying to send group emails through CiviMail:

Error in call to Mailing_send_test : DB Error: unknown error

```
Aug 27 15:28:58  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_5999aedd9eade6251afdc6974a96b5b1` (contact_id int, group_id int, UNIQUE UI_contact_group (contact_id,group_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_5999aedd9eade6251afdc6974a96b5b1` (contact_id int, group_id int, UNIQUE UI_contact_group (contact_id,group_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `civicrm_tmp_e_gccache_5999aedd9eade6251afdc6974a96b5b1` (contact_id int, group_id int, UNIQUE UI_contact_group (contact_id,group_id)) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci [nativecode=1787 ** Statement violates GTID consistency: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE and DROP TEMPORARY TABLE can only be executed outside transactional context.  These statements are also not allowed in a function or trigger because functions and triggers are also considered to be multi-statement transactions.]"]
)
```

I've tried cleaning up caches but stumped for any other ideas.  Please help.

Kind regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Alex, Welcome to Civi stackexchange.

If the server is running with global transaction identifiers (GTIDs) enabled (gtid_mode=ON), do not enable binary logging. Try turning it off

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. These are the settings - gtid_mode=OFF and log_bin=ON.  Perhaps setting enforce_gtid_consistency=OFF may fix it?

Comment: Yes may be... Can you try..

Comment: Oof. Seems that we can't get admin privileges on phpMyAdmin to change variables, as a result of shared hosting.